# Cant Opening Apache Server while using xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

While opening Apache server ON XAMPP problem is coming that it was not properly shut down

I am hereby attaching the error

```
Problem detected!
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    Port 8080 in use by "Unable to get info" with PID 6572!
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    Port 443 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware-hostd.exe" -u "C:\ProgramData\VMware\hostd\config.xml"" with PID 2808!
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
3:47:51 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:47:52 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: It's telling you pretty clearly what the problem is. I am not sure anyone here can explain it better than the Apache error messages. You need to find and shut down the processes using the ports Apache wants or reconfigure it to use different ports.

Comment: Thanks I got the solution, My VLC is working with same pid so hats why its not opening Once I closed my vlc window then it started workking

Thanks for considering my problem @James McLeod

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 applications that are blocking your ports, 443 and 8080.
443 is occupied by vmware which you can probalby change to something else.
8080 is used by unknown application.
You can change both ports on xampp configuration if you don't want to hunt which process used which port.